# How to write a multi-sign application using chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I want to write a financial exchange example. A stock is received successfully if there are signatures from both the seller and the broker. Could you share some ideas to do it with chaincode?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is:

1. Use the user certificate (your users would be the broker and seller) to sign the stock (the [API](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/CoreAPI.md#registrar) allows you to retrieve the ECert, enrollment certificate).
2. Store the signature in the World State (you can use a struct to store together the signatures and the stock, like [Marbles app chaincode](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles-chaincode/blob/master/hyperledger/part1/part1_chaincode.go))
3. When you store and retrieve the signatures you can use the chaincode to check the signatures. In [this example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management.go) you can see that it stores the admin certificate and checks signatures.

Comment: I was calling isCaller in this example https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/asset_management.go. 
It always returned failing. Do you have any idea about this?